# Ajax Event rowToggle is not working inside composite component

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the composite component for dataTable where I would like to add the ajax event="rowToggle". I tried the below options:

```
<cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="rows" />
        <cc:attribute name="value"
            type="org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel" />
        <cc:attribute name="var" />
        <cc:attribute name="id" />
        <cc:attribute name="rowStyle" required="false"/>
        <cc:attribute name="ajaxEvent" required="false" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <p:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.value}" id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
            paginator="true" rows="25" 
            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords}"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            lazy="true" rowStyleClass="#{cc.attrs.rowStyle}">
             <p:ajax event="#{cc.attrs.ajaxEvent}" global="false" />
             <c:set target="#{component}" property="var" value="#{cc.attrs.var}"/>
            <cc:insertChildren />
        </p:dataTable>
    </cc:implementation>
```

And from the main page, I am calling:

```
<t:lazydatatable var="changeSummary"
                        value="#{changeLogInspectorBean.changeLogInsertModel}" rows="25"
                        id="change_overview_insert" ajaxEvent="rowToggle">
```

It is failing with the below error message:

```
<p:ajax> Event:#{cc.attrs.ajaxEvent} is not supported.
```

Can you suggest what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct PrimeFaces version ?

Comment: Yes it is version: 3.5

Answer (score 0):

as for the ajax event call in a composite component you need to define the proper event in your table.

Try declaring the attribute like:

```
<cc:attribute name="rowToggleListener" required="false" />
```

And the actual call inside the datatable like:

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle"  listener="#{cc.attrs.rowToggleListener}"/>
```

And for the component:

```
<t:lazydatatable var="changeSummary"
                 value="#{changeLogInspectorBean.changeLogInsertModel}" 
                 rows="25" id="change_overview_insert" 
                 ajaxEvent="#{yourBackingBean.onRowToggle}">
```

The Mthod inside your backing bean could look like this:

```
public void onRowToggle(RowToggleEvent evt){
    MytoggledRowObject rowObject = ((MytoggledRowObject) event.getData());
}
```

Hope that helped :)